# ng2-pdf-viewer showing error in angular 13.2.2 and ionic 6

Tags: angular, pdf, ionic-framework, npm

error message
 `this is the pdf error Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot load script at: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.5.207/pdf.worker.min.js".`

using the ng2-pdf-viewer version
6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the pdf.worker.min.js library from the repository.

Then I added the path in the angular.json, in the root directory of the project.

```
{
  "glob": "pdf.worker.min.js",
  "input": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/",
  "output": "/assets/js/"
}
```

And finally, add the following code to your component:

```
(<any>window).pdfWorkerSrc = 'assets/js/pdf.worker.js';
```

With that it is already displayed correctly on the devices, but I don't know why this problem occurs, because in the browser it worked fine. If you find out more share!